# create virtual environment for Python 3.4-Django 1.7 in Windows with another vers of Python installed

Tags: django, windows, virtualenv

I am new in web programming, so just starting with Python and Django.
I am working on Windows 7 and already have Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.5 for a project I am working on.

For another project I need a virtual environment with Python 3.4 and Django 1.7 so I did:

1. install Python 3.4 in another folder  (c:\python34)
2. create a folder for my new project (my_proj) and here executed:

   > > c:\python34\python -m venv py34env
   >
   > > py34env/bin/activate
   >
   > > django-admin.py startproject --template='my proj github archive' env my_proj
   >
   > > cd my_proj
   >
   > > pip install -r requirements.txt
   >
   > > cd src
   >
   > > python manage.py migrate

The file requirements.txt contains among other packages Django 1.7

Now command manage.py migrate gives an error:  it seems it doesn't find Django.
If I do django --version I get no result, but if I do pip freeze it shows me Django 1.7.

Any help will be apreciated,
Thanks a lot,
Dani

Answer (score 0):

When working with Python on Windows, I always install virtualenvwrapper-win: https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win to get all the same convenience commands that you have on Linux or OS X.

You can create a virutalenv for Python 3.4, or any other Python runtime using the -p option (short for --python) and specifying the path to the Python executable:

```
mkvirtualenv my_env -p C:\python34\python.exe
```