# Python Virtual environment can not be activated (windows 7)

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed python on Windows and build a virtual environment. The first virtual environment is working. But when i try to run a second virtual environment it creates the environment as the first one but when i try to "activate" the second one,

> .\newenv\Scripts\activate

(activate.ps1 is neither working)

it answers:

> you must 'source' this script: PS> . .\newenv\Scripts\activate

Of curse, there is no "source" command on Windows 7 Powershell. What seems obscure to me is that the first virtual environment was running at the first try, so i though there would be no problems, but it seems as if it seems to lack something.

Answer (score 0):

please install virtualenv in the Scripts folder of your new environment and activate it by using name
  `activate newvenv`

Comment: The objective is to create a new environment to prohibit site effects. Therefore a new virtual environment is created. That was my understanding of the purpose of the virtual environment.

Comment: have u created an environment or want to make a new environment and activate it for further use

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Activating new python environment on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759582/create-virtual-environment-for-python-3-4-django-1-7-in-windows-with-another-ver)
The only way it worked for me was the creation of the environment with this command:

> python -m venv py34env

After that, I was able to activate the new environment with:

> py23env\Scripts\activate

I don´t know what the reason for this behavior is, i guess that Windows 7 is not much in use so this problem was simply not discovered yet(?)